# How to make image rotation and 3D transform simultaneously?

Tags: iphone

I am working on image editing application(resize, rotation, 3d transform). If I am rotate the image and then make 3D transform. Its going to initial image. Otherwise I am change the 3D transform then make rotation, Its also goes to the initial state.

For image 3D Transform I am using below code :

```
- (void)moveImage:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
        if ([recognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(translationInView:)]) {
            CGPoint translation = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view.superview];

            CALayer *layer = self.layer;
            CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
            rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0;
            rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, - self.xTranslation / 50.0 * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
            rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = - 1.0 / 500.0;
            rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, - self.yTranslation / 50.0 * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
        }
 }
```

For image Rotation I am using below code :

```
- (void)rotateImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (state == RSImageViewStateResizing) {
        recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
        recognizer.rotation = 0;
    }
}
```

How to I fix this issue. Always welcome your suggestions, sample code, Sample project, any App store applications. Thanks in advance. Any one help me.

Comment: Any one help me... I am in critical situation..

Answer (score 0):

Use CAAnimationGroup to combine multiple animation into one

```
CAAnimationGroup *theGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
theGroup.animations=[NSArray arrayWithObject:resizeAnimation, rotationAnimation, 3d transformAnimation];// add here your CAAnimation reference and CATransform3D reference
[layer addAnimation:theGroup forKey:@"animatePosition"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...Can you explain about CAAnimationGroup... I am does not work with CAAnimationGroup.