# How to make UNDO action for image editing(Resize, Rotation, 3D Transform)?

Tags: iphone

How to make the UNDO action in image processing? If I am change the image position(Resize, Rotation, 3D Transform) then click UNDO button, I want the previous state of the image. How to do? Please give sample source code or give some idea about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: keep track of what the previous state was, then when the user taps undo, go back. what have you tried?

Comment: I'm confuse that, if you're developing editor kind of app, and you're asking for `UNDO` logic! :) Never mind! I've not worked such kind of project but, you've to store last action performed, if user presses `UNDO` that would be load as changes to current action!!

Comment: My App is image editing so user can change the image. They click on the undo button, show the previous image. IS it clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `NSDictionary` with all `effects` providing / or can be applid with your `editor`

1. Store `NSDictionary` into an `NSMutableArray` with `[lastEffectArray addObject:effectDictionary];`
2. If user presses UNDO, load and applied `effectDictionary` effects from `lastEffectArray` with `key/value` pair. Here, you can do  two things :

Can `Remove` last `effectDictionary` object from `lastEffectArray` or, `Add` it for REDO action into other array.

Your `effectDictionary` should store each & every effects which can be available or applied with your `editor`. You can make some easy-to-use function to apply / remove effects!!!

Lastly, don't forget to `[release]` all effects Array & dictionaries.

Note, This isn't a solution, but can be implemented with own innovative logic.

Comment: @Mani, Nope I haven't any! It's a logic I supposed you should try! All the best :)

Comment: Hi Hemang...Please see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525414/how-to-make-image-rotation-and-3d-transform-simultaneously    this is my another question... any idea about this...

Answer (score 0):

The common way of implementing undoable operations is storing the state after every operation. So, in this case, you could

1. Store every version of the image. This is extremely inefficient regarding memory.
2. Store every transform step; when one transform is to be undone, you can just apply the inverse of the transform to the image. This is a preferred approach.

Comment: @Mani you better store the transforms themselves. You can do so by wrapping them into an NSValue and adding those NSValues to an NSMutableArray.

Comment: How to use NS Value. I am not using this one. Can you help me.

Comment: @Mani https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Mani I don't have it at hand, but it should be quite easy to come up with some.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16958/discussion-between-mani-and-h2co3)

Comment: Hi H2CO3...Please see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525414/how-to-make-image-rotation-and-3d-transform-simultaneously    this is my another question... any idea about this...